# user to change size of div using the row-resize cursor - like codepen.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit of a problem.

If you have ever used codepen.io, you can see that the user can change the size of the scripts dynamically using their cursor to make the scripts bigger /smaller, as the following screens shots illustrate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the graphics, the user is able to manipulate the script sizes to their personal specification. How is this done? Is there a plug-in that i can use?

I have researched for some time (as one should always do before asking a question on Stack Overflow), and I just can't seem to find the answer!

I would include a snip-it of code in this question, its just that i don't know where to even begin.

Thanks in advanced!

PS. I want the user to be able to control the widths of the scripts left-to-right and up-to-down, so basically the user can control the size in any direction.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=resize+element+by+dragging+mouse – lots of stuff right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a million and one ways to do this, and I suggest you just use an existing framework like [Dojo or something](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html)...

But if you absolutely must have custom code, the general gist of it is create a container with relative positioning, then create embedded containers that are absolutely positioned according to the parent container. (forgive the inline styles for example)

```
<div class="SplitContainer" style="position:relative">
    <div class="ContentPane" style="position:absolute">
        Some Text
    </div>
    <div class="Divider" style="position:absolute"></div>
    <div class="ContentPane" style="position:absolute">
       Other Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Use mouse events (mousedown, mouseup, mousemove) to detect when the user has clicked on the divider. You can use information from these events to determine the mouse position (evt.pageX, evt.pageY).

Then do lots of maths to determine the left, right, top, bottom of the absolutely positioned containers.

Simple Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ox6m29f1/